# Function equal its integral implies zero function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that
$$f(x) = \int_0^xf(s)ds $$
and $f(1) = 0$. Can we prove that $f=0$ without resorting to ODE solving techniques?

Comment: If you have a reason for " without using (whatever)", you should state it clearly *in the body of your question*. Otherwise, it just reads like "do it blindfolded, with your hands tied behind your back". And this site is about mathematics, not about stunts.

Comment: As is you'll get numerous answers just stating $f'=f\implies f(x)=ae^x$ then $a=0$. So maybe you should ask, can we prove $f=0$ without resorting to ODE solving, for instance using only mean value theorem, or without resorting to differentiation using only inequalities (e.g. $f$ continuous, let suppose $f\neq 0$ then $f(x)\ge M>0$ on $[a,b]$...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the differential equation you derived implied that $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( f(x+y)f(x-y)\right)=f'(x+y)f(x-y)-f(x+y)f'(x-y) =0.$$
And hence that $$f(x+y)f(x-y) = g(x).$$
We can specify the function $g$ by letting $y = 0$ to get
$$f(x)^2 = g(x)$$

and hence

$$f(x+y)f(x-y) = f(x)^2.$$

now sub $x=y$ and note that $f(0) = 0$ to get that

$$f(x)^2 =0$$

Comment: Where is this coming from ?

Answer (score 1):

Put $g(x) = |f(x)|$. Note that for $x \ge 0,$ we have

$$g(x) = |f(x)| = \left|\int_0^x f(s) {\rm d}s\right| \le \int_0^x |f(s)| {\rm d}s = \int_0^xg(s) {\rm d}s.$$

(The reason for assuming $x \ge 0$ is to have the integration in the "correct" order and not worry about extra modulus signs.)

Thus, we have
$$g(x) \le \int_0^x g(s) {\rm d}s.$$

Using [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality), we directly get the answer. I give a proof anyway.

---

Putting $G(x) := \displaystyle\int_0^x g(s) {\rm d}s,$ we see that $G'(x) \le G(x)$ or $G'(x) - G(x) \le 0.$ Also, note that $g \ge 0$ and thus, $G(x) \ge 0$ for $x \ge 0$.

Multiplying with $\exp\left(-\displaystyle\int_0^xG(t){\rm d}t\right),$ we see that
$$(G'(x) - G(x))\exp\left(-\displaystyle\int_0^xG(t){\rm d}t\right) \le 0$$
or that
$$\left(G(x)\exp\left(-\displaystyle\int_0^xG(t){\rm d}t\right)\right)' \le 0.$$

Thus, $$G(x)\exp\left(-\displaystyle\int_0^xG(t){\rm d}t\right)$$ is a decreasing function. However, note that the above is a nonnegative function which is $0$ at $x = 0$. Thus, we must have $G(x) = 0$ for all $x \ge 0$ and thus, $g = G' \equiv 0$ on $[0, \infty)$. A similar argument shows the same for $x < 0$ as well. Thus, we get $g \equiv 0$ or that $f \equiv 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a straightforward way to get your result. You will have
$$
f(1)=\int_0^1f(s)ds=0.
$$
This identity can be solved taking for example $f(s)=Ce^s$ because the exponential has the property to be equal to its integral. Putting this in the above equation will yield $C=0$ and you are done.

Comment: This only proves that there is no solution of the form $Ce^s$ with $C\ne0$.

Comment: The other route is to say that this is an integral equation with the only solution $f(s)=0$.

Comment: Uniqueness is ruled out.

Comment: No, in the current OP's question, ODEs are ruled out.